# Do something on every page

Tags: koma-script

I want to know how to do something on every page. I'm just curious. I have checked KomaScript source code, but it is too complicate and too difficult for me. I tried to see how `\lohead` was made. This "doing something on every page" bothers me a lot. I need to know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It mostly depends on *what* you want to do on every page.

Comment: `everyshi` would be a way of doing certain kinds of things on every page. As a matter of fact, there's a lot of things you can do with it on every page.

Comment: I guess (perhaps I'm wrong) what he is asking for. \lohead is related with making headers with koma-script. So the question should be: what is the mechanism behind adding text or pictures to every page. Memoir, eso-pic and many other packages also provide this functionality. Pure LaTeX also can put \thepage in footers. Unfortunately I can't answer, I'm not familiar with (La)TeX back-end.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what do you want to know exactly? How to repeat something on every page, with a special package, how to do it with plain TeX?

Comment: Even if the question is put on hold, to protect against a bunch of vague answers because of a vague question: it can be reopened once the question is clarified, don't worry, you can edit the question text to show the specific problem.